# <form> tag is not shown when created with php

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have this code:

```
$html .='<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="input_clone_id" name="input_clone_id" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="input_clone_var" name="input_clone_var" value="V"/>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" id="input_clone" multiple="multiple" /><br />
    <input type="submit" style="margin-left:0;float:left" value="Upload Files" />
</form>';
$html .='<a href="#" onclick="$.ajax({type: \'POST\',url: \'delete_pic.php\',data:{id:\''.$row['id_vila'].'\',var:\'V\',val:\''.$val.'\'},cache: false});window.location.reload( true );" style="background:url(\'images/icons/delete.png\') 50% -19px no-repeat;width:16px;height:16px;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-top: 6px;"></a>';
```

everything is created correctly except the `<form>` tag. It is not shown.
What am I doing wrong in here?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
function formatImage2($col,$val,$row)
    {
        $html = '';
        $new = explode( ';', $val );

        for($j = 0; $j < count($new)-1; $j++) 
        {
            $html .= '<a target="_blank" href="../images/gallery/'.$new[$j].'"><img style="border: none;" src="../images/gallery/'.$new[$j].'" alt="'.$new[$j].'" width="100" /></a>';
        }
        $html .='<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" id="input_clone_id" name="input_clone_id" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="input_clone_var" name="input_clone_var" value="V"/>
                        <input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" id="input_clone" multiple="multiple" /><br />
                        <input type="submit" style="margin-left:0;float:left" value="Upload Files" />
                </form>';
        $html .='<a href="#" onclick="$.ajax({type: \'POST\',url: \'delete_pic.php\',data:{id:\''.$row['id_vila'].'\',var:\'V\',val:\''.$val.'\'},cache: false});window.location.reload( true );" style="background:url(\'images/icons/delete.png\') 50% -19px no-repeat;width:16px;height:16px;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-top: 6px;"></a>';

        return $html;
    }
```

I'm using this to format pictures from the database.

OUTPUT:

```
<td>
                        <input type="hidden" id="input_clone_id" name="input_clone_id" value="9">
                        <input type="hidden" id="input_clone_var" name="input_clone_var" value="V">
                        <input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" id="input_clone" multiple="multiple"><br>
                        <input type="submit" style="margin-left:0;float:left" value="Upload Files">

                <a href="#" onclick="$.ajax({type: 'POST',url: 'delete_pic.php',data:{id:'9',var:'V',val:''},cache: false});window.location.reload( true );" style="background:url('images/icons/delete.png') 50% -19px no-repeat;width:16px;height:16px;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-top: 6px;"></a></td>
```

Comment: What are you doing with `$html`?

Comment: 'fess up! what **DID** you do to `$html`??

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Zk15e4). You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Consider reading up on `heredoc` syntax - this type of massive HTML string approach is just painful to look at, and work with

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the code (or at least what you're doing with `$html`) and then show the source from the web browser perspective?

Comment: Make sure your html is OK. All tags properly closed.

Comment: Such a lot of HTML defined in a variable is not the correct approach

Comment: So **just** the `<form>` tag doesn't show up, or the entire form doesn't show up?

Comment: @kacey just the form tag

Comment: I have put the output code too

Comment: Are you getting your output from **View Source** or **Inspect Element**? If I have malformed html (e.g.: `<p class="a" class="b">`), then it will display as I wrote it when I **View Source**. However, when I **Inspect Element**, then Chrome or Firefox will edit the HTML (e.g.: it turns into `<p class="a">`). Maybe there is an open `<form>` tag on the page before your code is rendered?

Comment: from the inspect element

Comment: when I echo this `$html` then I get normal output

Comment: @user123_456 Try using View Source. If you use Chrome or Firefox, you can right click on the page and click **View Source** from the menu (there are similar features in Safari and IE, but I don't know offhand how to do it). If the `<form>` tag appears there, then the HTML before the `<form>` tag might be interfering with it. Look for other `<form>` tags. If it isn't there, then _maybe_ you are using a framework (e.g.: cakePHP or Joomla) that doesn't allow the `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by having one form nested in another. The inner form tag will not be rendered, but any html inside that form will be.

You must have some form wrapping this one in your outside HTML.

```
<form id="outsideForm">
    <form id="insideForm">    
        <div>Inside Content</div>
    </form>
</form>
```

Inside form element disappears -
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j7th9/)

I posted this info 3 hours ago, but it was downvoted/deleted because it was in the form of a question. I would have posted the info as a comment, but I didn't have the reputation to do so. A better solution would probably have been to edit my answer, instead of removing it completely.

Comment: David you were right! Very good answer. The form was indeed wrapped inside. Keep a good work!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is good. Whenever you write the HTML code and try to print in PHP then always use the PHP's pre-build function [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Like:

```
echo htmlentities($html);
```

This function is used to identify the HTML code in PHP string and to encode that.
Try this. This will work for you.

Before using it you need to decode your string in HTML entities.
Use such as:

```
$html .= html_entity_decode('<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">');
```

This is an example. you need to do with all string to escape with special characters.
Here is the [tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) of this.

**EDITED:**

```
 $html .= <<<HTML

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" id="input_clone_id" name="input_clone_id" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="input_clone_var" name="input_clone_var" value="V"/>
                        <input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" id="input_clone" multiple="multiple" /><br />
                        <input type="submit" style="margin-left:0;float:left" value="Upload Files" />
                </form>

HTML;
```

Try this.

Comment: I am only getting text as output instead of html elements when using your answer

Comment: @user123_456 have you use `html_entity_decode` function to decode your code.

Comment: yes I have used `html_entity_decode` and `htmlentities` at the end.

Comment: @user123_456 are you using the wamp server? well try with the `<<<HTML` tag. I have edited the post and use that. Hope this will help you sure.